# Valgrind error: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value

Tags: c, initialization, malloc, valgrind, cs50

this is my first post here so apologies for any norms broken...
I am completing the Speller problem for Harvard's Cs50. The task is to load a dictionary file into a hash map and then check a text file for misspelled words.
My program runs fine and passes all tests except for the valgrind test.
Here is my code for the problem, there is another harvard-written file that contains the program's main and calls all of the funcitons I wrote:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table

typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node* next;
}
node;

void deleteList(node* n);
bool checkList(node* n, const char* checkword);


// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 21952;

// Hash table
node* table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char* word)
{
    int code = hash(word);
    return checkList(table[code], word);
}

int dictSize = 0;
bool dictLoaded = false;

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char* word)
{
    int index = 0;
    //char* wordCopy = malloc((sizeof(char) * strlen(word))); //VALGRIND ERROR Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value
    char* wordCopy = calloc(strlen(word), sizeof(char));
    strncpy(wordCopy, word, strlen(word)); //this line


    int sum = 0;
    //iterate thru the word until it ends or we get to our requisite 3 characters
    //must accomodate any capitalization or apostraphes
    while (word[index] != '\0' && index < 3) // this line is still an an error, just like when word was wordcopy
    {
        //change chars to int vals so that null is 0, a is 1, z is 26, and ' is 27
        int ascii = 0; // this remains unchanged if the current char is null
        if (isalpha(wordCopy[index]) != 0)
        {
            wordCopy[index] = tolower(wordCopy[index]);
            ascii = wordCopy[index] - 96;
        }
        else if (wordCopy[index] == '\'')
        {
            ascii = 27;
        }

// add the current chars val to the sum of the word's first three vals
// the math here ensures that "null null null" will be 0, and ''' will be 21,951 or the last index of our hash map
    if (index == 0)
        sum += ascii * 784;

    if (index == 1)
        sum += ascii * 28;

    if (index == 2)
        sum += ascii;

    index++;
    }


    free(wordCopy);

    return sum;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{

    FILE* dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");



   int wordLen = 0;
   char* tmpWord = malloc((sizeof(char) * 45) + 1);

   //hard code the first word

   // this first word would screw our loop bc the loop compares the null at the end of a word to a previous null
   //this first word has no previous null to compare to
    int index = 0;

    char c;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, dict))
    {

        if (c != '\n')
        {
            tmpWord[index] = c;
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }


    if (index < 1)
    {
        printf("first word broke load function\n");
        return false;
    }
//find some memory for our word
    node* firstNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

    //copy over the word into the node
    strncpy(firstNode->word, tmpWord, index);

    int code = hash(firstNode->word);

    firstNode->next = table[code];
    table[code] = firstNode;
    dictSize++;


    int lastNull = index - 1;
    int tmpWordIndex = 0;

    //now we can loop thru that ish!
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, dict))
    {


        if (c != '\n' && c != '\0')
        {
            tmpWord[tmpWordIndex] = c; //this starts copying into the tmp word at 0
            tmpWordIndex++;
        }
        else // we have reached the end of a string, dictionary[i] == \0
        {
            wordLen = index - lastNull - 1; // -1 for the new line characters

            //create a new node to store this new word
            node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

            // then we actually copy the word over from tmpWord
            strncpy(newNode->word, tmpWord, wordLen);

            code = hash(newNode->word);

            //insert node at the beginning of our list by changing pointer to current first item
            //then change the head node at table[code] to point to our new node
            newNode->next = table[code];
            table[code] = newNode;
            dictSize++;

            //reset the word index so that the next word will copy into the start of tmp word
            //reset the last null encountered to our current char, a null
            tmpWordIndex = 0;
            lastNull = index;

        }


        index++;
    }
        //do it all once more outside loop to grab the last character
            wordLen = index - lastNull - 1; 
            node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
            strncpy(newNode->word, tmpWord, wordLen);
            code = hash(newNode->word);
            newNode->next = table[code];
            table[code] = newNode;


    
    free(tmpWord);
    dictLoaded = true;


    fclose(dict);
    return true;

}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    if (dictLoaded)
    {
        return dictSize;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    bool unloaded = false;
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        node* tmp;
        while(table[n] != NULL)
        {
            tmp = table[n];
            table[n] = table[n]->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
        if(n == N-1)
        {
            unloaded = true;
        }
    }

    return unloaded;
}

void deleteList(node* n) 
{
    // base case is if next pointer is null
    if (n->next == NULL)
    {
        free(n);
        return;
    }

    deleteList(n->next);
}

bool checkList(node* n, const char* checkword)//recursion brah
{
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (strcasecmp(n->word, checkword) == 0) //error here, see below


// VALGRIND ERROR Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s): (file: dictionary.c, line: 258)
//Use of uninitialised value of size 8: (file: dictionary.c, line: 258)


    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return checkList(n->next, checkword); 
    }

}
```

harvard's check tests are giving me an error for these lines in particular:
within the hash(const char* word) function

```
char* wordCopy = calloc(strlen(word), sizeof(char));
strncpy(wordCopy, word, strlen(word));
...
while (word[index] != '\0' && index < 3)
```

I have tried changing the malloc to a calloc. I have tried increasing and decreasing the size of the memory I ask malloc/calloc for by 1 i.e.
`malloc((strlen(word) +/- 1) * sizeof(char)).`
The original code compared the wordCopy[index] in the while loop, but word[index] still gives the same error.
I have tried running the --track-origins=yes arg on valgrind (see below), but that does not give me anything, only harvard's tests actually show me the error.

```
speller/ $ valgrind -s --track-origins=yes ./speller
==7117== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7117== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7117== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7117== Command: ./speller
==7117== 
Usage: ./speller [DICTIONARY] text
==7117== 
==7117== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7117==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7117==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==7117== 
==7117== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7117== 
==7117== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Harvard's test show the following:

```
running valgrind --show-leak-kinds=all --xml=yes --xml-file=/tmp/tmpqjc7357q -- ./speller substring/dict substring/text...
checking for output "MISSPELLED WORDS\n\nca\ncats\ncaterpill\ncaterpillars\n\nWORDS MISSPELLED: 4\nWORDS IN DICTIONARY: 2\nWORDS IN TEXT: 6\n"...
checking that program exited with status 0...
checking for valgrind errors...
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s): (file: dictionary.c, line: 45)
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s): (file: dictionary.c, line: 46)
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s): (file: dictionary.c, line: 57)
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s): (file: dictionary.c, line: 267)
Use of uninitialised value of size 8: (file: dictionary.c, line: 267)
```

45, 46, and 57 are the lines within the hash function that are mentioned above. Line 267 is the following, found in the checkList function at the bottom of the code.

```
if (strcasecmp(n->word, checkword) == 0)
```

This is my first coding class, and this particular issue has entirely halted my progress. I apologize if the code isn't much of a looker. Thanks for reading through my post!

EDIT: below are dictionary.h and speller.c, both pre-witten for me...

```
// Declares a dictionary's functionality

#ifndef DICTIONARY_H
#define DICTIONARY_H

#include <stdbool.h>

// Maximum length for a word
// (e.g., pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)
#define LENGTH 45

// Prototypes
bool check(const char* word);
unsigned int hash(const char* word);
bool load(const char* dictionary);
unsigned int size(void);
bool unload(void);

#endif // DICTIONARY_H
```

```
// Implements a spell-checker

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Undefine any definitions
#undef calculate
#undef getrusage

// Default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

// Prototype
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for correct number of args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./speller [DICTIONARY] text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Structures for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // Benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // Determine dictionary to use
    char *dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;

    // Load dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Exit if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Try to open text
    char *text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(text, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // Prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Spell-check each word in text
    char c;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file))
    {
        // Allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // Append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // Ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // Consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file) && isalpha(c));

                // Prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // Ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // Consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file) && isalnum(c));

            // Prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // We must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // Terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // Update counter
            words++;

            // Check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
            bool misspelled = !check(word);
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // Update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);

            // Print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                printf("%s\n", word);
                misspellings++;
            }

            // Prepare for next word
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(file))
    {
        fclose(file);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Close text
    fclose(file);


    // Determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Unload dictionary
    // causing core dump!!
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n",
           time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    // Success
    return 0;
}

// Returns number of seconds between b and a
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a)
{
    if (b == NULL || a == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((((a->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_utime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_utime.tv_usec)) +
                 ((a->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_stime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_stime.tv_usec)))
                / 1000000.0);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
pm100's answer helped alleviate everything except for the while loop check in my hash function. I think all of the words I am passing into hash should be null terminated in the appropriate index. I will leave up my old code as a reference.
Below is my current code for the relevant functions. I have added the nulls in my load function, as this function was passing jarbled strings to the hash function that is giving the error.
To get rid of the malloc errors in hash, I figured I could just copy the char at the current index rather than refrence a copy of the entire word passed into the function. That helped. But for some reason comparing the d char to a null in the while loop condition is no good.

```
// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char* word)
{
    int index = 0;

    int sum = 0;
    //iterate thru the word until it ends or we get to our requisite 3 characters
    //must accomodate any capitalization or apostraphes
    char d = word[0];
    while (d != '\0' && index < 3) // this line is still an an error, just like when it word was wordcopy
    {

        //change chars to int vals so that null is 0, a is 1, z is 26, and ' is 27
        int ascii = 0; // this remains unchanged if the current char is null
        if (isalpha(d) != 0)
        {
            d = tolower(d);
            ascii = d - 96;
        }
        else if (d == '\'')
        {
            ascii = 27;
        }

// add the current chars val to the sum of the word's first three vals
// the math here ensures that "null null null" will be 0, and ''' will be 21,951 or the last index of our hash map
    if (index == 0)
        sum += ascii * 784;

    if (index == 1)
        sum += ascii * 28;

    if (index == 2)
        sum += ascii;

    index++;
    d = word[index];

    }



    return sum;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
    FILE* dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");



   int wordLen = 0;
   char* tmpWord = malloc((sizeof(char) * 45) + 1);

   //hard code the first word

   // this first word would screw our loop bc the loop compares the null at the end of a word to a previous null
   //this first word has no previous null to compare to
    int index = 0;

    char c;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, dict))
    {
        //printf("%c\n", c);
        if (c != '\n')
        {
            tmpWord[index] = c;
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    tmpWord[index] = '\0';

    if (index < 1)
    {
        printf("first word broke load function\n");
        return false;
    }
//find some memory for our word
    node* firstNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

    //copy over the word into the node
    strncpy(firstNode->word, tmpWord, index + 1);

    int code = hash(tmpWord);


    firstNode->next = table[code];
    table[code] = firstNode;
    dictSize++;


    int lastNull = index - 1;
    int tmpWordIndex = 0;

    //now we can loop thru that!
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, dict))
    {

        if (c != '\n' && c != '\0')
        {
            tmpWord[tmpWordIndex] = c; //this starts copying into the tmp word at 0
            tmpWordIndex++;
        }
        else // we have reached the end of a string, dictionary[i] == \n
        {
            wordLen = index - lastNull - 1; // -2 for the null and new line characters

            //create a new node to store this new word
            node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
            tmpWord[tmpWordIndex] = '\0';
            // then we actually copy the word over from tmpWord
            strncpy(newNode->word, tmpWord, wordLen + 1);
            //insert node at the beginning of our list by changing pointer to current first item
            //then change the head node at table[code] to point to our new node
            newNode->next = table[code];
            table[code] = newNode;
            dictSize++;

            //reset the word index so that the next word will copy into the start of tmp word
            //reset the last null encountered to our current char, a null
            tmpWordIndex = 0;
            lastNull = index;

        }


        index++;
    }

            wordLen = index - lastNull - 1;
            node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
            tmpWord[tmpWordIndex] = '\0';
            strncpy(newNode->word, tmpWord, wordLen);
            code = hash(newNode->word);
            newNode->next = table[code];
            table[code] = newNode;



    free(tmpWord);
    dictLoaded = true;

    fclose(dict);
    return true;

}
```

This line `while (d != '\0' && index < 3)` inside the hash function is still returning the conditional jump valgrind error.

Comment: can we have dictionary.h please

Comment: immediately obvious is that this ` char* wordCopy = calloc(strlen(word), sizeof(char));` doesnt reseve enough space, you need strlen +1 bytes to allow for trailing \0, use `strdup`

Comment: @pm100 I tried adding 1 to strlen(word) before multiplying by sizeof(char) in previous versions of the code to no avail... Will attempt strdup

Comment: @pm100 replaced the lines ```char* wordCopy = calloc(strlen(word), sizeof(char));``` and ```strncpy(wordCopy, word, strlen(word));``` with ```char *wordCopy = strdup(word);``` and received the same uninitialized error from valgrind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok your main problem is with null terminators, I dont understand a lot of you logic , I just called load with a simple 4 word file.

You must make sure that you make enough space for the null and you must make sure that you have a null.

so

the ones I found, you have to fix the others

```
char c;
while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, dict))
{

    if (c != '\n')
    {
        tmpWord[index] = c;
        index++;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
tmpWord[index] = 0; <<<<===== add the null at the end
```

and

```
   //copy over the word into the node
   // +1 for the null
    strncpy(firstNode->word, tmpWord, index + 1);
```

now in hash

```
char* wordCopy = calloc(strlen(word)+1, sizeof(char));
strncpy(wordCopy, word, strlen(word)+1);
```

+1, +1

there are others I am sure.

The reason valgrind is complaining is becuase without the trailing null functions like strlen will keep readin memory till they do find a random null, valgrind sees you reading characters from waaaay off the end of what you copied

To make sure you have the null, put a printf or simply pause in the debugger and look at a string. If you see

```
 "cat"
```

things are good, but if you see

```
 "cat!!@*foodle!....ll"
```

then you know you have missed the null

Comment: I think I did what you said, thanks for the help!